# Forget Password doesn't route to api using Pug

Tags: node.js, pug

I am trying to reset the password using nodejs , express and using template engine PUG , but for some reason , when i click submit after entering email id, nothing happens.

Below is forget-password.pug located in root/views/users

```
block content
  div.container
    div.row
      div.col
        h1 Forgot password
        p Enter your email address below. If we have it on file, we will send you a reset email.
        div.forgot-message.alert.alert-success(style="display:none;") Email address received. If you have an email on file we will send you a reset email. Please wait a few minutes and check your spam folder if you don't see it.
        form#forgotPasswordForm.form-inline(onsubmit="return false;")
          div.form-group
            label.sr-only(for="email") Email address:
            input.form-control.mr-2#emailFp(type='email', name='email', placeholder="Email address")
          div.form-group.mt-1.text-center
            button#fpButton.btn.btn-success.mb-2(type='submit') Send email
 
  script.
    $('#fpButton').on('click', function() {
      $.post('/api/users/getUsers', {
        email: $('#emailFp').val(),
      }, function(resp) {
        $('.forgot-message').show();
        $('#forgotPasswordForm').remove();
      });
    });
```

user.router is located at /root/users/user.router.js

```
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/forgetPassword", forgetPassword); //api to handle forget password and send email

router.get('/x/forget-password',function(req, res, next) { 
  res.render('users/forget-password', { });
});
module.exports = router;
```

I am using the url (http://localhost:1111/api/users/x/forget-password) to access the forget password page , but after entering an email and clicking submit, nothing happens, seems like its not able to call the post api /forgetPassword

Answer (score 0):

Use the corresponding route `/forgetPassword` and wrap your js event in a jQuery [`.ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler:

```
script.
    $(function () {
        $('#fpButton').on('click', function () {
            $.post('/forgetPassword', {
                email: $('#emailFp').val(),
            }, function (resp) {
                $('.forgot-message').show();
                $('#forgotPasswordForm').remove();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: I wrapped it now but still it doesnt work